# Postgres - не активируется расширение в рамках схемы

Tags: postgresql

я мигрирую бд с помощью `pg_dump` и `pg_restore`.

```bash
pg_dump -Fp -vbOx -f dump.sql -h $SOURCE_HOST -p $SOURCE_PORT -U $SOURCE_USER $SOURCE_DATABASE
psql $DIST_DATABASE -h $DIST_HOST -p $DIST_PORT -U $DIST_USER -c "drop schema \"elp-tst\" cascade;"
psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 $DIST_DATABASE -h $DIST_HOST -p $DIST_PORT -U $DIST_USER -f dump.sql
```

В процессе возникает следующая ошибка

```
psql:dump.sql:151: ERROR:  function elp-tst.uuid_generate_v4() does not exist
LINE 2:     "actionId" uuid DEFAULT "elp-tst".uuid_generate_v4() NOT...
```

Просмотрев файл дампа нахожу следующие строки

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp" WITH SCHEMA "elp-tst";
COMMENT ON EXTENSION "uuid-ossp" IS 'generate universally unique identifiers (UUIDs)';
CREATE TABLE "elp-tst".action (
    "actionId" uuid DEFAULT "elp-tst".uuid_generate_v4() NOT NULL,
...
```

При этом `SELECT * FROM pg_extension;` выводит `uuid-ossp`.
Совершенно без понятия, в чем может быть проблема, буду рад любым идеям.

Comment: покажите `\dx`. Может быть, что этот extension у вас уже поставлен в другой схеме? В public, например.

Comment: Да, как раз так и оказалось, что он существует в public. Но теперь я не могу понять, почему он недоступен из elp-tst

Comment: потому что там у вас не `DEFAULT public.uuid_generate_v4()`, а чётко указанный `DEFAULT "elp-tst".uuid_generate_v4()`. Это другая функция.